# positioning span element on the right of a div

Tags: css

The following html shows a item information. I'm trying put the avaliation span on the right of the rating div. If I float the rating to the left, it goes to the top of the another span. I'm sure it's a easy problem to solve, but I tried a lot without find out a solution that avoids dirty code.

```
                <div>
                    <h1>name</h1>
                    <span>omg: <a href="#">omg</a></span>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <span class="stars-2">
                            <img src="stars.png" width="86" height="91" title="4 star rating" alt="4 star rating" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <span>x avaliations</span>
                </div>
```

The rating CSS:

```
        div.rating {
            position: relative;
            width: 84px;
            height: 14px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        div.rating span {
            position: absolute;
            left: -1px;
        }

        div.rating span.stars-0 {
            top: -1px;
        }

        div.rating span.stars-1 {
            top: -16px;
        }

        div.rating span.stars-2 {
            top: -31px;
        }

        div.rating span.stars-3 {
            top: -46px;
        }

        div.rating span.stars-4 {
            top: -61px;
        }

        div.rating span.stars-5 {
            top: -76px;
        }
```

Comment: Can you draw an image of what you want to achieve ? Or are you flexible at changing markup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `style="float:left;"` to the rating `div` and the aviliations `span`. (Better yet: add `float:left;` to the CSS file for these elements).

Then, put `<br clear="all" />` before the rating `div` and after the avaliations `span`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display:inline` to the rating div

```
    div.rating {
        position: relative;
        display:inline; /* add this */
        width: 84px;
        height: 14px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

here + more styling to get it to fit http://jsfiddle.net/j5mxZ/ -- Edit without styling http://jsfiddle.net/j5mxZ/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of the spans in your HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1>name</h1>
    <span>omg: <a href="#">omg</a></span>
    <span>x avaliations</span>
    <div class="rating">
        <span class="stars-2">
            <img src="stars.png" width="86" height="91" title="4 star rating" alt="4 star rating" />
       </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about it don't you like? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I don't like the idea of the html order being different from the presentation order.

Comment: Understood. You may want to edit your question and add that then.